# MS Word "and" Funktion

Tags: function, ms-word

I'm trying to do a conditional **Textblock** in Word with 2 Conditions.
The text should be shown if the MergeField "Bewertungsergebnis" is between 79 and 90.

This is what I've tried:

```
IF {MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis \* Mergeformat } >= 90 "text1" ""}

IF " =AND({MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis \* Mergeformat } >= 80 ; {MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis \* Mergeformat }) < 90 "text2" ""}

IF {MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis \* Mergeformat } < 80 "text3" ""}
```

Text 1 and 3 are working fine, but text 2 is either shown always or shown never.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is as simple as:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis}< 80 "text3" {IF{MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis}< 90 "text2"  "text1"}}
```

or even:

```
{=INT({MERGEFIELD Bewertungsergebnis}/10)-8 \# "'text1';'text3';'text2'"}
```

if the text strings are short enough and don't themselves contain quotes.

You don't need the MERGEFORMAT switches.